# Difference between "cpu usage" and "cpu activity log" in xcode instruments?

Tags: xcode, xcode-instruments

When using the template "Time Profiler", xcode by default logs "CPU Usage". If you click the "Add library" button (plus sign on top right of UI), there is something called "CPU Activity Log".

Apple has references pages for both but they don't help me understand the difference between them. Reading through that it seems "CPU Usage" has more detail than the other. They also provide different percentages of cpu "usage/activity".

Does anyone know the difference between these?

Reference pages from Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Instrument-TimeProfiler.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Instrument-CPUActivity.html

Image of timeline pane
[image]

Thanks in advance!